# Trying to use a series as a variable name for a dict

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, series

So I've created a Pandas dataframe from a CSV file. The csv file is from http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html. Specifically I am interested in finding the most popular airports for a month, and for each airport I want to gather and manipulate data for Origin, DayofMonth, UniqueCarrier, Taxi time = TaxiOut + TaxiIn (where destination), WeatherDelay, Dest. I'm trying to output a csv with the information for the most popular airports.

To do this, I am creating dictionaries (in Python in Jupyter Notebook, working with Apache Spark). Below in my code I'm trying to gather each Origin (airport name) and create a dictionary that will have an array with delays per day, an array of carriers at that airport, the length of taxi time, the total planes taxiing (departing as well as arriving), an array of weather delays per day, and an array of destinations from that airport.

```
for x in range(len(df2.index)):
    if df2["Origin"] not in locals():
        df2["Origin"] = {'Days': [0]*31, 'Carriers': [], 'TaxiSum': 0, 'TaxiNum': 0, 'Weather': []*31, 'Dest': []}
```

### I get the error below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last 
<ipython-input-93-8b0de59b6cd2> in <module>()
1 for x in range(len(df2.index)):
----> 2     if df2["Origin"] not in locals():
3         df2["Origin"] = {'Days': [0]*31, 'Carriers': [], 'TaxiSum': 0, 'TaxiNum': 0, 'Weather': []*31, 'Dest': []}

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __hash__(self)
    875     def __hash__(self):
    876         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
--> 877                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
    878 
    879     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

So I would like to create a variable with the same name of the series (in this case, the "Origin" airport), but it seems to interpret what I am doing as something else.

Comment: `df2["Origin"]` is never in `locals()`, so the `if` statement is useless. Also, you never use `x` in your loop, and the value of `df2["Origin"]` is constantly overwritten.

Comment: @DYZ Right, so instead I would be trying to see if the variable version of df2["Origin"] exists, so I am still trying to see if I can create a variable with the same name as the series. Do you/anyone else think you can give me any direction with that?

Comment: Is there any point with continuing with my approach, or should I try making a list of dictionaries? I was really hoping to be able to associate each airport with the variable name, (so I could easily call access airport["Carriers"] and find all the carriers at that airport) but it doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: tl;dr. But to answer your comment question, yes, abandon the for loop approach, if that's what you mean. Pandas should very easily get you what you want without any looping. That said, your given example is too complex, start with an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a better response.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to loop each row for but in each iteration, you are trying to access the whole column Origin.

Can you try the following to see if it works?

```
for x in range(len(df2.index)):
    if df2.iloc[x]["Origin"] not in locals():
        df2.iloc[x]["Origin"] = {'Days': [0]*31, 'Carriers': [], 'TaxiSum': 0, 'TaxiNum': 0, 'Weather': []*31, 'Dest': []}
```

Comment: Any member of any DataFrame is never going to be in locals ().